# how to open a URL in default browser onclick?

Tags: android

I have a webview, i want to handle all URL's inside the webview, which is working fine. however, i want to add a button which would get current page's URL and ask user to choose a browser to open the URL in.
here is what i have tried so far, but  i can't figure out how to pass the URL to the intent, i only know how to get URL-

```
public void downloadvia (View view, String string) { 
    String uriUrl = webView.getUrl();  
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent();  
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
```

obviously it force closes as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriUrl));
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

Comment: uriUrl is still yellow underlined and not being used

Comment: yep, it is force closing

Comment: Make sure manifest includes the following in the declared activity:           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action. launchBrowser" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: i am not trying to open my webview from another browser. I am actually trying to open another browser with my webview

Comment: You must make sure you have declared the intent filter in the relevant activity declaration in your manifest file, as above, cannot edit my answer with the code, it won't let me. :)

Comment: I know, should be at a party somewhere... got flu so make the most of it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mUrl));
    Intetn chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "dialog title");
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

You need to set the action and data of `Intent` so android will know what exactly you want.